# Joining one table json column with another table column

Tags: php, json, laravel, eloquent

I want to join the two tables using a json column. Actually I want to fetch all the users emails which has id in my json column (member_ids). So far I tried this much:

```
$team=DB::table('users')
     ->join('teams','users.id','teams.member_ids->id')
     ->select('teams.*','users.email')
     ->where('teams.id',$id)->first();
dd($team);
```

but this dd gives me null. Please help me to solve this

Comment: What database and Laravel version are you using?

Comment: sorry bro i already re-architect my database so i don't need this now